# Hangman Program Malfunction

Tags: python

I am brand new here, and as far as I could tell, no one has asked the specific question I have. If some one has though, feel free to link me to the question.

Anyways, I am going through an invent with python book(Invent your own computer games), and am trying to complete the "Hangman" chapter. The problem that I'm having is that whenever I enter a letter, whether it is correct or not, the program still draws pieces of the Hangman. I'm currently running Python 3, which the book says it uses. Here is my code:

```
import random
HANGMANPICS = ['''

 +---+
 |  |
    |
    |
    |
    |
===========''','''

 +---+
 |  |
 O  |
    |
    |
    |
===========''','''

+---+
 |  |
 O  |
 |   |
    |
    |
===========''','''

+---+
 |  |
 O  |
/|   |
    |
    |
===========''','''

+---+
 |  |
 O  |
/|\ |
    |
    |
===========''','''

+---+
 |  |
 O  |
/|\ |
/   |
    |
===========''','''

+---+
 |  |
 O  |
/|\ |
/ \ |
    |
===========''']

words = 'ant baboon badger bat bear beaver camel cat clam cobra cougar \
coyote crow deer dog donkey duck eagle ferret fox frog goat goose hawk \
lion lizard llama mole monkey moose mouse mule newt otter owl panda parrot \
pigeon python rabbit ram rat raven rhino salmon seal shark sheep skunk sloth \
snake spider stork swan tiger toad trout turkey turtle weasel whale wolf wombat\
zebra'.split()

def getRandomWord(wordList):

    wordIndex = random.randint(0, len(wordList)- 1)
    return wordList[wordIndex]

def displayBoard(HANGMANPICS, missedLetters, correctLetters, secretWord):
    print(HANGMANPICS[len(missedLetters)])
    print()

    print('Missed letters:', end ='')
    for letter in missedLetters:
        print(letter, end = '')
    print()

    blanks = '_' * len(secretWord)

    for i in range(len(secretWord)):
        if secretWord[i] in correctLetters:
            blanks = blanks[:i] + secretWord[i] + blanks[i+1:]

    for letter in blanks:
        print(letter, end = '')
    print()

def getGuess(alreadyGuessed):

    while True:
        print('Guess a letter.')
        guess = input()
        guess = guess.lower()
        if len(guess) != 1:
            print('Please enter a single letter')
        elif guess in alreadyGuessed:
            print('You have already guessed that letter. Choose again.')
        elif guess not in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz':
            print('Please enter a LETTER')
        else:
            return guess

def playAgain():

    print('Do you want to play again?(yes or no)')
    return input().lower().startswith('y')

print('H A N G M A N')

missedLetters = ''
correctLetters = ''
secretWord = getRandomWord(words)
gameIsDone = False

while True:
    displayBoard(HANGMANPICS, missedLetters, correctLetters, secretWord)

    guess = getGuess(missedLetters + correctLetters)

    if guess in secretWord:
        correctLetters = correctLetters + guess

        foundAllLetters = True

    for i in range(len(secretWord)):
        if secretWord[i] not in correctLetters:
            foundAllLetters = False
            break

    if foundAllLetters:
        print('Yes! The secret word is "'+ secretWord +'"! You have won!')
        gameIsDone = True
    else:
        missedLetters = missedLetters + guess

    if len(missedLetters) == len(HANGMANPICS) -1:
        displayBoard(HANGMANPICS, missedLetters, correctLetters, secretWord)
        print('You have run out of guesses!\nAfter ' + str(len(missedLetters)) + ' missed guesses and ' + str(len(correctLetters))+ ' correct guesses, the word was "'+ secretWord +'"')
        gameIsDone = True

    if gameIsDone:
        if playAgain():
            missedLetters = ''
            correctLetters = ''
            gameIsDone = False
            secretWord = getRandomWord(words)
        else:
            break
```

Comment: What is the name of the book?

Comment: The `if len(missedLetters) == len(HANGMANPICS) -1:` clause should be indented to be under the `else:` of the preceding conditional.

Comment: Dumping your entire program here is not really acceptable. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I'm sorry, I honestly didn't know( I saw others with their whole program up), and I also didn't know quite where I went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is where you've placed the condition for a missing letter - even correct guesses end up being treated like 'missed letters'.

In your code:

```
else:
    missedLetters = missedLetters + guess
```

comes a long way after the original check for whether a letter is in the word.

It works if you move the clause to here:

```
if guess in secretWord:
    correctLetters = correctLetters + guess
    foundAllLetters = True

else:
    missedLetters = missedLetters + guess
```

In this case, the missed letter gets added to the missed letter list only if it's not in the secretWord.

With that change, things seem to run okay for me.

Comment: :D Thank you so much. I honestly thought I had the code correct, but I didn't. That fixed the problem perfectly. I can't up vote you yet though.